How could this creature use firearms?
This is a species that has human-level intelligence and very similar to a bonobo/chimpanzee, so it's clear to see why they may struggle with guns. Hard to see how they could shoulder many kinds of guns like a human, among other feats of the body's mechanics when aiming and absorbing recoil in an ergonomic way. They're short, hunched, have long arms/short legs, good climbers and walk with the aid of their hands (said hands are like humans but smaller, more flexible and larger palm).
How could this species use their body effectively enough doing very delicate work such as carrying firearms? Highly noticeable changes to the body, guns, certain techniques or pretty much anything else are welcome.

How do you mean carry? On a belt holster/sling-strap... What answers have you considered and dismissed, and what was the reason? I'm having trouble seeing the problem here (I'm a fan of Planet of the Apes - all versions).

Oh, I mean using them because it's hard to see how such a creature could shoulder an M16 and start laying down firepower. I should edit the question to say use rather than just 'carry'.

Well, yes please, you could add the bit about specific weapons too, just so as we get the idea of what they're trying to accomplish with the things.

@Terra could make your question a little more clear as it is all over the place. Like how can they have human intelligence and also chimpanzee Intelligence? Also do you want to know how to modify the gun so this creature could use them or do you want an explanation on how they carry guns? And what kinds of guns do you even mean?

The would of course use pistols and rifles designed for their anatomy, and not pistols and rifles designed for human anatomy. There is no way to design firearms adequate for their anatomy except by, you know, actually designing firearms adequate for their anatomy. (And please note that chimpanzees and bonobos can walk on two legs when they need to or just want to, and they very often stand on their hind legs when the activity requires it.)

why would they have a problem with guns, guns tailored to their anatomy an not ours would work just fine. the anatomy of a chimp is really no that different than a human. especially not in the arm.

@John strangely the human body is really well suited as a tool user. A Chimp however cannot really properly stand up right and might have a harder time aiming. There is also no immediate way to fix this except for maybe weapons with less knockback so smaller calibers.

@Fallenspacerock So the chimp lays down... or braces the barrel on a tree limb... or the stock is designed for the chimp's physiology... which is the point everyone's making. Human physiology is irrelevant. Chimps with human-level intelligence will design weapons suitable for themselves.

@Terra, I believe the problem people are having with this question is that it's not well focused. Your species will develop weapons that are suitable for themselves, which makes the question somewhat moot. What, then, is the real problem here? If you're trying to crowbar designed-for-human weapons onto your species then you'll have trouble... but we could deal with that (kinda a Planet of the Apes scenario). But we'd need to know that's the case. If it's not the case, then we need to better understand what the problem is you're trying to solve. Thanks.

@JBH Yes that may be the case i just said that it would have a problem using normal human weapons.

@JBH That's the entire point of the question, I do not know what that would look like

@Fallenspacerock none of which has impede holding the gun. A chimp would have a hard time making a gun, but holding and firing a gun is fine with their anatomy. as long as the gun is made to their proportions they should have no problem. the differences in the arm anatomy are mostly in proportions. there are plenty of things they would have trouble with, holding a fitted gun would not be one of them.

@John while you are right there is still the problem of chimps not being able to stand up right for an extended period of time. Which is crucial for using most guns. Also i think their balance is worse.

@Terra Are you asking us for help developing weapons for your simian-esque creatures, or are you asking for help rationalizing how your simian-esque creatures can use human weapons? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what you need and why you need it. Thanks.

@Fallenspacerock it's really not, most militaries train to fire from a hunched bent knee stance.  straight knees make you less stable and less mobile, locked knees is for target shooting. soldiers actually train to assume a MORE chimp like stance.

@John i don't know to much about military training to be honest. Still though i think a chimpanzee has probably less  coordination in human stances in general. So it would make sense for them to use guns differently or make them differently.

Of course they have poorer coordination, they have much smaller brains, but you specified human level intelligence.

Firearms are Primarily a product of the environment that they are used in
I am going to attempt to condense the last ~150 years of Military Firearm development here to give you some ideas about the How/Why.
So - at end of the 19th Century, when Smokeless powder was introduced - most Militaries adopted a Rifle Calibre of around 7-8 mm (.303 British, 30-06 for the US 8 mm Mauser etc.)
The reason why was due to the colonial wars that had been fought up to that time,  Game hunting by Nobility, Performance on the Firing range/competition and military doctrine in regards to massed volley fire at longer distances (2000 yards, for example).
In short - when you are fighting an enemy on nice open ground, who are charging at you with Melee weapon, a calibre that is capable of being lethal out to 1000+ Metres and taking down everything from a sheep all the way up to a large Deer/Elk (which includes a Man...) is a great choice - plus, when all your bigwigs come and see the marksmanship competitions, it makes you look good.
This remained through WW1 until WW2 - Enter the Intermediate cartridge.
Turns out that without Optics - identifying and successfully engaging a man-sized target at more than 400 metres is really difficult. Plus all that weight of Ammunition is a logistical pain, not to mention the Recoil - which, if you want semi-auto or controlled full-auto fire is an issue.
Not to mention that fighting in the confined streets and cities of Europe means your sightlines aren't the open plains of Africa, but are much more restricted. So most militaries transitioned to something smaller - 5.56 Nato, 7.62 Russian, 7.92 Kurz etc.
Plenty good enough to engage in a target within 400 metres, smaller and lighter (so better for logistics) and less Recoil meaning when you shoot full auto, most rounds are going in the approximate location.
And this remained the standard from WW2 till basically Afghanistan - now we have open  plains again, but we also have Modern Optics - and the 5.56 is loosing out to full-power rifle cartridges at the longer ranges.
Now we have the .277 Fury - which is a compromise between the Full-power Rifle cartridges of old and the intermediate cartridges widely used today. A bit more range for a bit more recoil.
I have abridged and glossed over a lot of detail - and I hope you have read this far - because here is the answer:
Your Creatures will design and use Firearms to be effective in the manner in which they fight
If they fight with a lot of Climbing and verticality - then you will probably see a lot of pistol type Firearms, possibly with braces firing something like an intermediate cartridge - you don't need Range, you need it to be punchy enough to deal lethal damage on the other end, but also light enough recoiling that you can fire one-handed whilst climbing.
So first think about how your creatures intend to fight, this will dictate your Firearm design.

So the weapon starts out as a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowgun that was worn dual use in the short version as a arm-brace and in the long version, as a sort of spear, walking stick or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_vault stick variant.
As technology progressed, things got weird.The bullets were still poisoned, but now the pipes were metal and for pressure after a side-episode involving pressurized containers and springs (imagine a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagpipes like compressed air vessel), powdered cartridges were introduced.
As silent hunting was still greatly valued, the cartridges burn in 3 stages, the first accelerating by creating gas, the 2nd lowering the noise by consuming gas, eating up half of the produced gas when the projectile reaches the muzzle. The last stage is similar to a rocket, igniting far away from the shooter, accelerating the dart- louder and more visible.
The newest in dart hunting today, is the telescopic "gun" which unfolds from a arm-container and is then fed with pretty low yield starter darts.
The pouches are still the same, leather, water-resistant, with buttons that will not open even if you hang upside down in a tree, readying yourself to rain death from above. No metal (to shiny), nothing that can make loud noises.
The darts are in bandoleers, each wrapped in a oiled paper container, to keep the rockets dry and ignitable. The bandoleers have metal on the inside to prevent any puncture by the poisons.
